# Codeception - Xpath in PHPBrowser and Array Fields

Tags: php, xpath, phpunit, codeception

This is sort of a 2 part question:

I'm using Codeception to test some Codeigniter code.  Just using Acceptance testing.  Lets say you have a field like:

```
<input type='text' name='materials[]' />
```

I've found that I have trouble filling this field using `fillfield('materials[]', 'some value');`.  It seems that `fillfield()` doesn't know what to do with the brackets

So from there, I figured I'd use Xpath instead of the input name, and avoid the brackets all together.  However, no matter what Xpath I try, the test always fails.  I've confirmed that the Xpaths work by using the Chrome console, but those same paths seem to fail in Codeception.

So my question is:  has anyone successfully dealt with array inputs in Codeception PhpBrowser, and how?  And has anyone successfully used Xpath in Codeception with PhpBrowser?  If so, is there perhaps a format, or escape character that needs to be accounted for when using Xpaths in Codeception?

Comment: any thoughts on this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using an older version of Codeception (1.8) which wasn't compatible with Xpaths. Codeception 2, however, seem to function with XPaths.